# Linker Error (SDL, OpenGL)

Tags: c++, c, opengl, sdl

I'm getting this error when trying to compile:

> *1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_FreeSurface referenced in function "private: unsigned int __thiscall objloader::loadTexture(char const *)" (?loadTexture@objloader@@AAEIPBD@Z) 1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol _SDL_LoadBMP_RW referenced in function
>   "private: unsigned int __thiscall objloader::loadTexture(char const
>   *)" (?loadTexture@objloader@@AAEIPBD@Z) 1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_RWFromFile referenced in
>   function "private: unsigned int __thiscall objloader::loadTexture(char
>   const *)" (?loadTexture@objloader@@AAEIPBD@Z) 1>main-light.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GetTicks referenced in
>   function "public: void __thiscall Player::init(void)"
>   (?init@Player@@QAEXXZ) 1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol _SDL_GetKeyState referenced in function "void __cdecl
>   Control(float,float,bool)" (?Control@@YAXMM_N@Z) 1>main-light.obj :
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_WarpMouse referenced in
>   function "void __cdecl Control(float,float,bool)"
>   (?Control@@YAXMM_N@Z) 1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol _SDL_GetMouseState referenced in function "void
>   __cdecl Control(float,float,bool)" (?Control@@YAXMM_N@Z) 1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _SDL_ShowCursor referenced in function "void __cdecl Control(float,float,bool)" (?Control@@YAXMM_N@Z) 1>main-light.obj :
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Delay referenced in
>   function _SDL_main 1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol _SDL_GL_SwapBuffers referenced in function _SDL_main
>   1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _SDL_PollEvent referenced in function _SDL_main 1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_SetVideoMode referenced
>   in function _SDL_main 1>main-light.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol _SDL_Init referenced in function _SDL_main
>   1>MSVCRT.lib(wcrtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   *wWinMain@16 referenced in function _*_tmainCRTStartup 1>C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Projects\FPS\Debug\FPS.exe : fatal error
>   LNK1120: 14 unresolved externals*

I tried to change to a console application and it didn't work. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: SDL surely comes with a couple of .lib files. You're forgetting to link against those. Make sure you do within your linker options.

Comment: I already did it (SDL.lib and SDLmain.lib).

Comment: show the command that does the linking

Comment: what do you mean? Properties -> linker -> input -> additional dependencies -> "SDL.lib; SDLmain.lib; glut32.lib"?

Comment: Any other error messages before the linker errors?

Comment: @TiagoSalzmann: I always thought that linker dependencies on MSVC do not need to be ";"-separated. Try removing semicolons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For OpenGL you may also need glu32.lib and opengl32.lib

Comment: glut32.lib should be fine, but opengl32.lib is needed too. And are you sure that u have configured SDL properly?

Comment: yes. i just added opengl32.lib and didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I copyed the SDL and OpenGL include and lib files in the main file of my project. Can it be the cause of the problem?

Comment: no, this is all i saw on the build tab

Comment: is the solution not related with

'1>MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup'?

Comment: His linker errors indicate that he does not link with SDL. Somehow. glu has nothing to do with it.

Comment: oh, so the problem is sdl. But what with SDL. I added SDL.lib and SDLmain.lib and that's everything that's needed. Maybe are the dll files causing any problem?

Answer (score 7):

Direct to the 32 bit versions of the library.